# HTML5 html-tag and DOCTYPE

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype

From what I've read, the correct way to start an HTML5 page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

With nothing more in those lines. Is this true? (I'm asking because Visual Studio has more than that.)

(Also, I'm wondering if HTML5 is really the current standard or should I be using XHTML5 or some other version.)

Comment: what does Visual Studio give you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [HTML living standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype) and [the W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-doctype), the doctype is the required preamble but required for legacy reasons. I quote:

> 1. A string that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string
>      `"<!DOCTYPE"`.
> 2. One or more space characters.
> 3. A string that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string
>      "html".
> 4. Optionally, a DOCTYPE legacy string or an obsolete permitted DOCTYPE
>      string (defined below).
> 5. Zero or more space characters.
> 6. A U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN character (>).
>
> In other words, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, case-insensitively.

And `<html></html>` for a valid document

> (Also, I'm wondering if HTML5 is really the current standard or should
>   I be using XHTML5 or some other version.)

It is not the current standard IMHO because it is not finished yet. But [this article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/24/top-10-reasons-to-use-html5-right-now/) explains very well 10 reasons for using it now.

Comment: Note that although WhatWG and W3C are working on different documents right now. That part is still the same: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-doctype

Comment: @Sebastian keen observation, should I change references?

Comment: Feel free to add "my" link to your answer - having both is probably the best solution...

Answer (score 4):

Mostly yes. But the HTML5 spec for [the `<html>` element says](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-html-element.html#the-html-element)

> Authors are encouraged to specify a lang attribute on the root html
>   element, giving the document's language. This aids speech synthesis
>   tools to determine what pronunciations to use, translation tools to
>   determine what rules to use, and so forth.

so better, for a page whose content is in American English, would be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
```

Also if you are using XHTML5 served as `application/xhtml+xml` you will need to add the namespace, and also the XML equivalent of the lang attribute making it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us">
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's true. No more complicated doctypes in HTML5. The new standard is simplified and there's only the one you said.

Comment: how do browsers that don't support html5 handle that doctype?

Answer (score 2):

According to the HTML5 drafts, “A [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype) is a required preamble”. The preamble `<!DOCTYPE html>` is recommended, but legacy doctypes are allowed as an alternative, though they “should not be used unless the document is generated from a system that cannot output the shorter string”. The only part that is required in addition to it is the `title` element, and even it may be omitted under certain conditions. The `<html>` tag is not required.

HTML5 is not a standard. It is not even a W3C recommendation (yet). What you should use depends on what you are doing. It does not really matter which version of HTML you think you are using. What matters is the markup you have and how browsers (and search engines etc.) process it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct as far as I know.